# Can I use the relay updater configs for updating the simple graphQL list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relay, relaymodern

I'm using the latest version of `relay` (1.6.0) in my project to handle fetching and updating data between client and server. I have a list of books and I get this list as a simple qraphQL list (not a edge/node list) from server.

This is my query for getting the list of books from server:

```
graphql`
  query BooksQuery {
    viewer {
      books {
        id
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

I have two mutations for adding and removing a book from database. I want to update my web page when I call any of these mutations. I know that I can use the `updater` function to update my UI but there is some configs like `NODE_DELETE` or `RANGE_ADD` for this kind of UI updates. How can I use these configs while my book list is a simple one and it's not a edge/node list?

Comment: Pretty sure you have to implement your list as a connection to be able to use the configs. Don't think there's a way around that, unless you implement the updater yourself like you said.